# Why was only the Silver medal awarded for music at the 1932s Olympics?

Tags: 20th-century, 1930s, olympics

At the 1932s Olympics, Chzechoslovakian composer Josef Suk won the Silver medal in the music category: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Josef_Suk_(composer)

I'm wondering why no gold or bronze medal was awarded?

If there is only one viable entrant, wouldn't that win gold automatically?

Comment: Music was judged differently - see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Art_competitions_at_the_Olympic_Games#Music)

Comment: I understand, but I can't find anything on how this particular competition was judged and why they would give out silver but not gold.

Answer (score 4):

Art competitions at the Olympics were always controversial, largely because of the professional standing of many of the participants, when the Olympics was supposed to be all amateur.  Music was not the only discipline in which only some - or no - medals were awarded see:-  http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Art_competitions_at_the_Olympic_Games

Comment: Still it's strange that if they're awarding just one medal, it's not gold, but silver...

Comment: @David hmmm maybe, perhaps they just didn't think it was good enough for Gold? I find the whole idea of an "Arts Olympics" a bit problematic - I  mean, in my field, Literature, how would you choose between, say Jane Austen and Charles Dickens?

Comment: I don't know, it's very arbitrary, but to award anything but gold if there is just one entry is a bit bizarre.

Comment: @SJuan76 That'll be Jane Austen, then!